# How to access two TYPO3 root folders one with "localhost " and other with "IP Address"

Tags: configuration, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I need to access two root folders (shown below) one with localhost as starting url and other with IP address as starting url. How can I configure it?

[image: Tree Image]

I have added Domain for  rootpage as shown below. But dosen't work 
[image: Domain name given in root]

I am using TYPO3 v6.2
Thanks in advance

Comment: @blesior . I need to look up my site in one template when I access like " http://localost/typo3site " in one form and when I access like  " http://192.168.1.22/typo3site" want to see the site in another template

Comment: Have you added a domainrecord for  192.168.1.22 too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a domain record to each root, the first one with domain 'localhost', the second one with the IP address as domain. If both hostnames are routed correctly, that should do it.

Comment: thank you for the replay .How can I set that.. ? can u show the method for it?

Comment: Select the a root page, then open the "List"-module in the menu, and select "new record". Then choose "domain record".

Comment: Is their any need for giving " Redirect to " in that new domain ?

Comment: No, in your case probably not - it can be useful for SEO, if you have multiple domains pointing to the same subtree

Comment: I have added the screen shot i did as u said. plz check the qus. Thank u

Answer (score 1):

Create two `vhosts` in your apache conf both pointing to the TYPO3 folder, i.e. `http://fakedomain1.loc` and `http://fakedomain2.loc` (also add it to your `hosts` file).

Then configure multidomain as described in documentation (as also Jost suggested)

The goal is to access the page by the domain only i.e. `http://fakedomain1.loc/` and not by `http://localhost/project-number-1234567`

Comment: Thank you. But I think its not the method I needed..I want to setup it in my typo3 ,not the apache.

Comment: You didn't understand me: create these vhosts to simulate different domains if you really use `localost/typo3site` as a path to page, TYPO3 checks only domain and domain is `localhost`

Comment: Thank u.your ans helped me for the configuration